# How to cancel manually a BackgroundService in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service, cancellation-token

I create a BackgroundService like this:

```
public class CustomService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        do
        {
            //...

            await Task.Delay(60000, cancellationToken);
        }
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

How to cancel it manually?

Comment: You can get a reference to it; `.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>().OfType<CustomService>().Single().MethodName(....)`. (or inject some other common service to indicate cancellation ... )

Comment: This way came to my mind, but I want to know if it can not be done through cancellationToken?

Comment: You don't need a reference to `IHostedService`. `BackgroundService` **is** an IHostedSevice. What do you mean `cancel it manually` though? Cancel all background services explicitly, and perhaps the application itself? Cancel one service but leave the others running?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you want some other service to locate your `BackgroundService` instance, you will need to do something like my sample above. If you register the service in another way, you'll have multiple instances.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want to cancel all services and maybe the application itself (or at least the host), or just a single service.

**Stopping the application**

To cancel the application, inject the [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) interface in the class that will force the cancellation and call [StopApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostApplicationLifetime_StopApplication) when needed. If you want to cancel from inside the background service itself, perhaps because there's nothing else to do, that's where you need to inject.

`StopApplication` will tell the host the application needs to shut down. The host will call `StopAsync` on all hosted services. Since you use `BackgroundService`, [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L60) will trigger the `cancellationToken` passed to `ExecuteAsync`:

```
public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Stop called without start
    if (_executeTask == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // Signal cancellation to the executing method
        _stoppingCts.Cancel();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
        await Task.WhenAny(_executeTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

}
```

You don't have to change your current code at all. The only concern is that `await Task.Delay()` leaks timers. It would be better to use a `Timer` explicitly, and dispose it when cancellation is triggered.

For example, if you want to shut down the application from a controller action:

```
public class MyServiceController:Controller
{
    IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    public MyServiceController(IHostApplicationLifetime lifeTime)
    {
        _lifeTime=lifeTime;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Stop()
    {
        _lifeTime.StopApplication();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Stopping the service**

If you want to stop just this one service, you need a way to call its `StopAsync` method from some other code. There are numerous ways to do this. One such way is to inject `CustomService` to the caller and call `StopAsync`. That's not a very good idea though, as it exposes the service and couples the controller/stopping code with the service. Testing this won't be easy either.

Another possibility is to create an interface just for the call to `StopAsync`, eg :

```
public interface ICustomServiceStopper
{
    Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token=default);
}

public class CustomService : BackgroundService,ICustomServiceStopper
{
    ...

    Task ICustomServiceStopper.StopAsync(CancellationToken token=default)=>base.StopAsync(token);
    
}
```

Register the interface as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICustomServiceStopper,CustomService>();
```

and inject `ICustomServiceStopper` when needed:

```
public class MyServiceController:Controller
{
    ICustomServiceStopper _stopper;
    public MyServiceController(ICustomServiceStopper stopper)
    {
        _stopper=stopper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Stop()
    {
        await _stopper.StopAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know all BackgroundService closes automatically when the app closes, right?

Answer (score 4):

It's late, but simply trigger **StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)** method, which is part of **BackgroundService** interface, it will only stop your current worker, not the whole app:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var stopCounter = 10;
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        stopCounter--;
        if (stopCounter < 1)
        {
            StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the [BackgroundService source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class)

and it looks like my previous answer was wrong.

The `ExecuteAsync` parameter is a token provided by the `StartAsync` method.

The `BackgroundService` token source is cancelled by the `StopAsync` method.

So to cancel the `CustomService` async work you have to call the `StopAsync` method. This cancel token provided to the `ExecuteAsync` method as parameter.

Comment: The OP already uses the CancellationToken. The question is how to trigger cancellation in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the OP uses cancellation token but is asking how to cancel. This looks a little bit wierd so I've shown two options how to cancel the Background service successor.

Comment: It's not weird at all - that's what happens when eg `Ctrl+C` is used in a service worker. It's not strange to want to explicitly stop a service either. What you posted doesn't do what you assume it does. `StopAsync` is already implemented in `BackgroundService`. It's used to *respond* to cancellation, not trigger it