# Why doesn't Background Service stop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, background-service, cancellation-token

I'm trying manually stop the class that inherit from `BackgroundService`.

ExampleService.cs

```
public class ExampleService : BackgroundService, IExampleService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExampleService> _logger;
    private bool stopRequested { get; set; }

    public ExampleService(ILogger<ExampleService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Stoping(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Stoping");
        stopRequested = true;
        await StopAsync(token);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && !stopRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            _logger.LogInformation("Service is working {0}", count++);
        }
    }
}
public interface IExampleService
{
    Task Stoping(CancellationToken token = default);

}
```

Call from API

```
[HttpGet("stoptask2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    await exampleService.Stoping();
    return Ok();
}
```

But the service doesn't stop. I know `IHostApplicationLifetime` is working but all application is stopping. I don't want this.

I have tried [How to cancel manually a BackgroundService in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898449/how-to-cancel-manually-a-backgroundservice-in-asp-net-core) but it doesn't work.

I know I should stop the service using stoppingToken in ExecuteAsync, but how?

Comment: You need to use a cancellation token. The current call to `Stopping` is using the default value which is essentially a dummy token, i.e., `CancellationToken.None`

Comment: Seems that this was answered quite well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898449/how-to-cancel-manually-a-backgroundservice-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel manually a BackgroundService in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898449/how-to-cancel-manually-a-backgroundservice-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @MetroSmurf I tried exactly the same, but don't working

Comment: The code posted shows there is no `CancellationToken` used; nothing will stop b/c the token does not signal the bg service to cancel it's operations.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I know that. I tried the solution you mentioned. I'm asking how can I stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the actual registration I can only guess, but I think problem is the registration - `AddHostedService` creates one service descriptor and when you register `IExampleService` it will create another unrelated one, so you have two different instances of service. Personally I would just use the separation of concerns principle and introduce separate service like `IStopper` which would have two methods `Stop` and `IStopped` (or expose a cancelation toke instead of the second one), but if you want to keep your current class/interface structure - then be sure to provide registration which will result in only one instance:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ExampleService>(); // singleton
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExampleService>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ExampleService>()); // reabstract as interface
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ExampleService>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ExampleService>()); // reabstract as hosted service
```

Comment: so how to the method to restart service? manually starting not working.

Comment: @OkanKaradag have not tried that and not sure ATM this would be correct approach but you can try calling `StartAsync` (and overload it to set `stopRequested` to false). Or use some synchronization mechanism (based on `SemaphoreSlim` or `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) instead just ending the loop on bool.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the CancellationToken in the Stopping and Execute methods cannot process because they are different objects. So if you use this figure, you will solve the problem.

```
public class ExampleService : BackgroundService, IExampleService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExampleService> _logger;
    private CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    private static bool stopRequested = true;

    public ExampleService(ILogger<ExampleService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (!stopRequested)
            {
                await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
            }
            await Task.Delay(3000, stoppingToken);
            _logger.LogInformation("ExampleService is working {0}", count++);
           
           
        }
    }

    public void Stoping() => stopRequested = false;
}
}

public interface IExampleService
{
    void Stoping();
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<HostOptions>(hostOptions =>
{
    hostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior = BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore;
});
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ExampleService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExampleService,ExampleService>();
```