# Asp.Net Core: Signalr: Queue: Pass group name into queue

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have an asp.net core project using signalr. I'm trying to pass group name as a parameter to my backgroundservice via a queue. The, in my hub, I wrote a function to join the group with the group name passed in from the javascript. I get just one message in my browser.

Here's my code:

LiveDataHub.cs:

```
public sealed class LiveDataHub : Hub     
{           
    private readonly IMyBackgroundQueue _queue;
    public LiveDataHub(IMyBackgroundQueue queue) => _queue = queue;

    public async Task JoinToGroup(string group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New group joined: " + group);            
        await _queue.QueueAsync(group);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {group}.");
    }
}
```

MyBackgroundQueue.cs

```
public interface IMyBackgroundQueue
{
    ValueTask QueueAsync(string item);

    IAsyncEnumerable<string> DequeueAllAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class MyBackgroundQueue : IMyBackgroundQueue
{
    //private readonly Channel<string> _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    private readonly Channel<string> _channel;
    public MyBackgroundQueue(int capacity)
    {            
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<string>(options);
    }
    public ValueTask QueueAsync(string item) => _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item);        
    public IAsyncEnumerable<string> DequeueAllAsync(CancellationToken ct) =>
        _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(ct);
}
```

MyBackgroundService.cs:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<LiveDataHub> _hub;
    public IMyBackgroundQueue _queue { get; }
    public MyBackgroundService(IHubContext<LiveDataHub> hub, IMyBackgroundQueue queue)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _queue = queue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var eventMessage = new Models.EventMessage($"Id_{ Guid.NewGuid():N}", $"Title_{Guid.NewGuid():N}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));                
            await foreach(var _item in _queue.DequeueAllAsync(stoppingToken))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("group name: " + _item.ToString());
                await _hub.Clients.Group(_item.ToString()).SendAsync("onMessageReceived", eventMessage, stoppingToken);
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }


        
    }
    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSignalR(hubPotions=> { hubPotions.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });

        services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();            
        services.AddSingleton<IMyBackgroundQueue, MyBackgroundQueue>(ctx => {
            return new MyBackgroundQueue(100);
        }); // I think the error is here on this line but I can't seem to figure out what it is
    }
```

javascript.js

```
const signalrConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/messagebroker")
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

signalrConnection.start().then(function () {
console.log("SignalR Hub Connected");

signalrConnection.invoke("JoinToGroup", "Group01")
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.toString());
    });

}).catch(function (err) {
    signalrConnection.stop();
    console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Comment: What does `get just one message` mean? When adding a group and sending messages, only one message is displayed? I tested your `BackgroundService` and `BackgroundQueue` with the [official example](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/signalr/groups/sample/), it seems that there is no problem.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Chen: From my ExecuteAsync code in my BackgroundService, my client should be receiving messages every second. I just receive one message and that's all. Also, how do I stop my background service when the browser disconnects?

Comment: About how to stop background service, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67901615/18789859).

Comment: @Chen: can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your `_queue.DequeueAllAsync(stoppingToken)` method, which causes this thread to wait all the time, so you can only enter `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)` when the program starts and when you click `JoinToGroup`.

You can use `TryRead` instead of `ReadAllAsync`:

MyBackgroundQueue:

```
public interface IMyBackgroundQueue
{
    //...
    IEnumerable<string> DequeueAllAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
public class MyBackgroundQueue : IMyBackgroundQueue
{
    //...
    public IEnumerable<string> DequeueAllAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (_channel.Reader.TryRead(out string? item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

MyBackgroundService:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    //...
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var eventMessage = new Models.EventMessage($"Id_{ Guid.NewGuid():N}", $"Title_{Guid.NewGuid():N}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));

        foreach (var _item in _queue.DequeueAllAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("group name: " + _item.ToString());
            await _hub.Clients.Group(_item.ToString()).SendAsync("Send", eventMessage, stoppingToken);
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000,stoppingToken);
    }
    //...
}
```

Note the way to register `MyBackgroundQueue`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyBackgroundQueue>(ctx => {
     var queueCapacity = 100;
    return new MyBackgroundQueue(queueCapacity);
});
```

Refer to [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks-1).

In addition, you can only send a message when you click `JoinToGroup`, because when you store the `groupName` in the `Queue`, it will be consumed in the background service, which means that every time you click, it will be stored in the `Queue` once, and after one second will delete it, `groupName` only exists in `Queue` for one second.

There is no [TryPeek()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.trypeek?view=net-6.0#system-threading-channels-channelreader-1-trypeek(-0@)) in [Channel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-5.0), but in [ChannelReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1?view=net-6.0) for .NET 6+. You can take a look at it if you have a business need.

About how to stop background service, you can refer to the two methods in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898449/how-to-cancel-manually-a-backgroundservice-in-asp-net-core/67901615#67901615).

For example, in `LiveDataHub`:

```
public sealed class LiveDataHub : Hub     
{
    IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    public ChatHub(IHostApplicationLifetime lifeTime)
    {
        _lifetime = lifeTime;
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        _lifetime.StopApplication();
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

In this way, it will stop your application.

Another way is to call `StopAsync()` in `OnDisconnectedAsync`, usage is similar to this.

**Edit:**

I found that there seems to be a problem with the second method of stopping the background service, it doesn't work in my code. I found a solution, hope it can help you.

MyBackgroundService:

```
public interface ICustomServiceStopper : IHostedService
{
    Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token = default);
}
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService, ICustomServiceStopper
{
    private static MyBackgroundService _instance;
    public static MyBackgroundService Instance => _instance;
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hub;
    public IMyBackgroundQueue _queue { get; }
    public MyBackgroundService(IHubContext<ChatHub> hub, IMyBackgroundQueue queue)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _queue = queue;
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        //...
    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
    { 
        base.StopAsync(token);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
services.AddSingleton<ICustomServiceStopper, MyBackgroundService >(serviceProvider =>
{
    return MyBackgroundService.Instance;
});
```

LiveDataHub:

```
public sealed class LiveDataHub : Hub     
{
    private readonly IMyBackgroundQueue _queue;
    private ICustomServiceStopper _customServiceStopper;
    public ChatHub(IMyBackgroundQueue queue, ICustomServiceStopper customServiceStopper)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _customServiceStopper= customServiceStopper;
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await _customServiceStopper.StopAsync();
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```